# Shared Access Database - Can't create lock file

Tags: ms-access

I am AccessConfused.

We have a shared(I have tried to get this office to switch to a different solution) server hosted Access database. Everything was working fine until Wednesday afternoon.

Issue: Only one user can open the Access DB at a time. Ldb file does not delete when the user closes the DB. If I open the file directly on the file server I an open a second but not more.

Checked: Permissions - gave everyone full control on the share. Restored the file from a backup from a few days ago. Tested on other file servers. Checked settings from a version of the file from 2020 and everything is the same.

I have rolled back server updates and endpoint updates with no fix. I cannot find any apparent issues.

Comment: Delete rights must be granted to both the _share_ itself and the shared _folder_.

Comment: An update: After running Wireshark I see the following error: STATUS_PENDING and STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION I do not see these errors when I am the only one to open the file. I moved the file to a new server and experience the same issue.

Comment: Experiencing the same. System run for years. Seems to be related to recent MS Office update.

Comment: Force an update now. That will get Version 2111 (Build 14701.20262 Click and run) where the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was related to the latest update.

Verified by rolling back using: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /update USER displaylevel=True forceappshutdown=true updatetoversion=16.0.14701.20226 in an elevated CMD prompt.

Comment: Force an update now. That will get Version 2111 (Build 14701.20262 Click and run) where the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

"Everything was working fine until Wednesday afternoon"
You have to think of any system change, OS(Operating system) or Non-OS that happened just before Wednesday or on Wednesday.

A working system just does not stop working.

Even though you wrote "I have rolled back server updates and endpoint updates with no fix. I cannot find any apparent issues.", there are still things that happened that you need to find out and roll back or uninstall.

Comment: We did not think to roll back Office updates. This was the fix. Support ticket opened with Microsoft on the issue.

Answer (score -1):

After installing KB5008212 a few hours ago, we can't access a Microsoft Access (Office 365) application on a file server that's been running fine for years.

We've been running Access version 2111 build 14701.20248. The Access build version doesn't seem to affect the inability to access the application.