# Microsoft Access DBEngine.OpenDatabase() breaks for Network-Paths - Error 3050

Tags: ms-access, database-connection

We have an Access Database-Solution with Frontend and Backend Database running for years.

Now within the last two days problems occurred. E.g.

```
        Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(strDatabasePath, False, True, "MS Access;PWD=" & strPassword)
```

Does result in Error 3050 - File could not be locked. ONLY when the Backend Database is on a network share (if it's on a local drive everything works as expected).

The error occurs on any share:

- a Shared Folder from a Windows PC
- a Shared (Samba) Folder on a NAS
- independently whether the share is accessed via a UNC-Path (\server\share) or a mapped drive-path.

The error was introduced by a faulty Office Patch (seems it was V2111 - 14701.20240)

In the first version of this post I thought that Windows-Update KB5008212 was causing the problem.

Thanks to @Gustav for identifying the problem.

How do we find out WHEN MS pleases to fix the problem?

Comment: I found  my workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70310028/shared-access-database-cant-create-lock-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Microsoft:

> This is due to today’s (Patch Tuesday) update to Office.  The problem
> was introduced by a security fix, so it impacts all active versions of
> Access. We are working on a fix, and will deliver it as quickly as
> possible.
>
> The update has only been set to automatically update a very small
> percentage of users, and it looks like we will be able to pause
> automatic updates, so it will not propagate.
>
> There will be a page added to the
>
> [Fixes or workarounds for recent issues in Access (microsoft.com)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fixes-or-workarounds-for-recent-issues-in-access-54962069-14f4-4474-823a-ff7e5974a570),
>
> which will then be the place to go
> for updates.
>
> These are the updates that introduced the problem:
>
> ```
> KB 5002104 for Office 2013
> KB 5002099 for Office 2016
> Office 2019 Version 1808, build 10381.20020
> Office LTSC 2021 Version 2108, build 14332.20204
> Microsoft 365 Apps:
>     Current Channel Version 2111, build 14701.20248
>     Monthly Enterprise Channel Version 2110, build 14527.20340
>     Monthly Enterprise Channel Version 2109, build 14430.20380
>     Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel (Preview) Version 2108, build 14326.20692
>     Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel Version 2102, build 13801.21086
>     Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel Version 2008, build 13127.21842
> ```
>
> If you did get updated to one of those builds, the only solution
> currently is to move back to an earlier build in the channel.

Comment: Not again. :( Is the above publicly available somewhere? -- Thank you for the info, and please update it if you get new information.

Comment: Not that I know of. The site will be the link I posted. I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav. Moving back to the earlier version fixed the problem. Initial Question updated.

Comment: The issue has a page now: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-error-could-not-use-path-to-database-accdb-file-already-in-use-6cbc1560-62c2-46e7-9980-d079a46f5acc (STATUS: INVESTIGATING)

Comment: Force an update now. That will get _Version 2111 (Build 14701.20262 Click and run)_ where the issue has been resolved.

Comment: No fix yet for Office 2019!

Comment: Note please, that the issue persists for shared _DFS_ paths. If so, for a workaround, use a UNC path to a specified server member.

Comment: NOTE: Force an update of Office 365 and it will fix the issue as of yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Installing version 2008, in fact, resolved the issue for me. Microsoft just released new builds of versions 2108 and 2112 yesterday, 01/11/2022, that also resolved this same issue for me.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score -1):

We had the same problems.

Uninstalling Office 365 (32-bits) and re-installing Office 365 (32-bits) from the OfficeWeb-Portal seems to solve the problem.

Comment: ... until the update is installed again.

Comment: This MS [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2bd5c457-a917-d57e-35a1-f709e3dda841) explains how to revert to an earlier version of Office and disable automatic updates.

Answer (score -1):

Ours is not manifesting in the same way.  I seem to get a lot of orphaned lock files.  Users are having some problems getting in to the databases but usually If I delete the lock file and have them wait 5 minutes, the problem goes away.  Since this started it has been a game of running daily backups to a separate file just in case.  Major Pain in the you know what.  I'll keep an eye on what crops up here.  Thanks folks (Yes this is more of a comment than an Answer, but I needed more characters)