# Starting Access database fails with 'file in use' error

Tags: ms-access

I start Access and open a database.
Can be either an accde or accdb.
Access shows up in task manager under Apps.

Close Access.
**Now, Access shows up in task manager under Background Processes.**

Start Access.  That works.
Open a database. Fails with

```
Could not use 'Admin'; file already in use.
```

I can't find this string anywhere in my code. And it seems to happen before it hits my first line of code.

End the process in Task Manager and now I can open the database, without reopening Access.

Procmon doesn't show any files being locked or any failing file reads.

I tried repairing Office. No change.

Access 365, v16.0.13801.21072, 64 bit

Comment: Do you have any code that runs when database opens or closes? Access app is not minimized to task bar? Longshot but this link describes issue with old versions http://access.mvps.org/access/bugs/bugs0005.htm

Comment: Likely a combination of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365001/microsoft-access-dbengine-opendatabase-breaks-for-network-paths-error-3050, which causes the lockup if the file is in use, and something else that keeps the databases open. If you update you can avoid the file in use errors, but probably not the underlying problem that keeps Access active